# How to Hide Dnsmasq version number?

Tags: security, dns, version, dnsmasq

It is possible to hide BIND DNS server version number, but how can you change it in dnsmasq?

command to execute:

```
dig localhost version.bind txt chaos
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if there exists a configuration option to hide `version.bind` in `dnsmasq`, but there exists a compile time option `NO_ID`

> ```
>  **Compile time option NO_ID**
>
>     Some consider it good practice to obscure software version numbers to
>     clients. Compiling with -DNO_ID removes the *.bind info structure.
>     This includes: version, author, copyright, cachesize, cache insertions,
>     evictions, misses & hits, auth & servers.
> ```

Here are the discussion threads for the same:

http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2016q3/010859.html
http://lists.thekelleys.org.uk/pipermail/dnsmasq-discuss/2016q3/010858.html